# Suspect UFW Firewall is blocking SSH, how to find port to enable it?

Tags: ssh, ufw

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, and am having with my SSH command. If I have my ufw firewall enabled, and ssh into some website, no password or username prompt comes up -- it just hangs in the terminal indefinitely.

If I type `sudo ufw disable` and try to ssh, it works fine.

So, the question is, what configurations do I need to have on ufw to enable ssh to work again? How does one view the ports which ssh uses? I've already searched through `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and didn't find any number which looked like a port number.

The output of `sudo ufw status` is:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             

25,53,80,110,443/tcp       ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
53,67,68/udp               ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
51413/tcp                  ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
51413/udp                  ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
6969/tcp                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
25,53,80,110,443/tcp (v6)  ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)             
53,67,68/udp (v6)          ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)             
51413/tcp (v6)             ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)             
51413/udp (v6)             ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)             
6969/tcp (v6)              ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
```

For a Ubuntu/Linux noob who just downloaded yesterday, any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: SSH uses port 22

Comment: So should it be "ALLOW OUT" then? If so, how does one do that via the Terminal?

Comment: If I do `sudo ufw allow 22`, it says `Skipping adding existing rule`.

Comment: @AvocadoSurprise *outgoing* SSH connections will use a non-privileged (random high-numbered) port. You don't need to open ports IN if you are connecting OUT. I'd recommend just sticking with the default UFW configuration (allow out; deny in) for now.

Comment: You can try `sudo ufw allow out 22` but I don't think it'll make any difference.

Comment: I followed @steeldriver's advice and did `sudo apt-get purge ufw` followed by `sudo apt-get install ufw`. Works now. Thanks, all! The reason why I had a certain custom configuration for ufw was I believe I was following one of the Ubuntu noob security guides, and it recommended that setup.

Comment: @AvocadoSurprise - You made sure to enable it again after reinstalling, right?